# How to show list dom revered in vue js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, vue.js

I want to show my vue js list in v-for reversed on dom. Object should not be change. Just created reversed list by v-for. HTML default list is top to bottom, I want to append items from bottom to top in dom. You can see telegram web messages list that do this with ng-repeat.

Is there any way to do this by v-for? or another option?

Thanks.

Comment: Why dont you reverse the array??

Comment: if you want to do this only in view, then use `orderBy` filter of angularjs specifying reverse as true. see this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

Comment: @Ashishsah good advice, but it should be noted that `.slice()` should be added first.

Comment: @the_mishra Thanks. It works.

Answer (score 0):

add to page controller

```
$scope.setOrderProperty = function(propertyName) {
if ($scope.orderProperty === propertyName) {
    $scope.orderProperty = '-' + propertyName;
} else if ($scope.orderProperty === '-' + propertyName) {
    $scope.orderProperty = propertyName;
} else {
    $scope.orderProperty = propertyName;
}
```

}

and

```
 $scope.sortType     = 'x.UserID'; $scope.sortReverse  = false; $scope.searchFish   = '';
```